# Accuracy SD not showing up in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I tried to follow the example codes at https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-machine-learning-algorithms-in-r/ but my output did not showing up accuracy and kappa sd. What am i missing? My caret library is 3.5.2 on Windows 10 Pro.

My output was:

```
Random Forest 

208 samples
 60 predictor
  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 186, 187, 188, 187, 188, 187, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.8376335  0.6712345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial it's not specified how the output with SD's was obtained. It actually wasn't just `rf_default`. Instead,

```
rf_default$results
#       mtry  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD   KappaSD
# 1 7.745967 0.8376335 0.6712345 0.07038106 0.1426329
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my day! I am too new to this R world.